# Changing value in Dictionary in a Array in UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a problem changing the value of a Dictionary in a Array

```swift
var array = (defaults.array(forKey: "Transactions")! as! [Dictionary<String, Any>])
        
(array.reversed()[index]["Title"] as! String) = titleTextField.text! // Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'String'
```

> Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'String'

This is the error I get back

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: What exactly is it you think you are casting to String? Skip the casting and realize that `reversed()` will return an immutable array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Joakim points out, array.reversed() returns an immutable array.

Try this:

```
guard 
  var array = (defaults.array(forKey: "Transactions")! as? [Dictionary<String, Any>]),
  let newText = titletextfield.text,
array[array.count-index]["Title"] = newText
```

(And then re-save your array to UserDefaults)

Comment: You can't have `var dict = array[array.count-index] ` inside a guard statements and the `dict` variable isn't really needed. After the guard do `array[array.count-index]["Title"] = newText`

Comment: Good point about not being able to guard indexing into an array. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One more step will work

```
if var array = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "Transactions") as? [Dictionary<String, Any>], let valueText = titleTextField.text {
    array.reverse()
    array[index]["Title"] = valueText
 }
```